# How to search for a substrings value inside of a string?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am trying to find the value of a property, inside of a string. In `<img src="invalidURL.com">` if the property/sub-string were to be `src`, I would want to recieve `invalidURL.com`.

In Violent Python it uses the line `imgSrc = imgTag['src']`, which does not givee a compiler error, and the script runs fine. (Full script can be found in [this Github repo.](https://github.com/shadow-box/Violent-Python-Examples/blob/master/Chapter-3/4-exifFetch.py)) However, when I tried to write my own script it gives a compiler error.

```
htmlImgTags = ['<img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png"/>', '<img src="asdasd">']
for tag in htmlImgTags:
    print tag
    tagSrc = tag['src'] 
    print tagSrc
```

The error complains about using a string as an index instead of an int.

```
<img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png"/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "looking in an array.py", line 4, in <module>
    tagSrc = tag['src'] 
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

What exactly is going wrong in my code, but not in the book's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you link to appears to be using a library called [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML. That loop is over a list of tag objects created by Beautiful Soup, not a list of the actual tag text.

Here's an example using [Beautiful Soup v3](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png"/>
<img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-49.png"/>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
html_img_tags = soup.findAll("img")

for tag in html_img_tags:
  print tag['src']
```

The output is:

```
/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png
/images/icons/product/chrome-49.png
```

Note that `tag` is **not** just a string, it's a BeautifulSoup tag object:

```
>>> type(html_img_tags[0])
<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
```

If you print it, it will display as a nicely formatted tag:

```
>>> print html_img_tags[0]
<img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png" />
```

But that's only because BeautifulSoup makes sure that the object converts itself to that string for easy inspection.

---

Note: if you happen to have BS4 on your machine instead, the import line should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

...and the `findAll()` function is now `find_all()`.

Comment: But in this case isn't tag a string containing `<img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png"/>` or am I desperately confused on what `soup.findAll` does?

Comment: No, it isn't. It's an object created by BeautifulSoup that represents that tag. Conveniently enough, when you print it, it looks like this: `<img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png" />` ...but that's only because BeautifulSoup makes sure that the object converts itself to that string for easy inspection. I added an explanation of this, let me know if it's clear :)

Comment: Thanks! +1 For writing an easily understandable answer, updating it, explaining the whole it prints making it look like a string thing, etc. I am going to need to open a meta post to figure out how to vote on the other answers. :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
tag = '<img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png"/>'
src = re.findall('src=(\".*?\")', tag)
print src # prints ['"/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png"']
```

Comment: I am trying to get `/images/icons/product/chrome-48 .png` not whether or not the string contains `src`.

Comment: @Cammy_the_block I misunderstood your question... check out the new edition ;)

Answer (score 1):

This would be more error free:

```
for tag in htmlImgTags:
    if tag.startswith('<img src'):
       tag = tag.split('"')[1]
       print tag
```

Comment: I am not trying to figure out whether it contains `src` or not. I am trying to figure out what the value of `src` is equal to. (in the case of `<img src="freddy">` `src`'s value would be `freddy`) I do like searching for `img` as well. (Which is not wanted in my case, but nice idea.)

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: check this

Comment: Is there supposed to be a link?

Comment: I added a line. tag will now contain the link as a string

Answer (score 1):

The source code you linked to is using a library called BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML. You appear to be trying to do this by hand, I assume for educational purposes.

You have a few options.

- One is to use an html parsing engine just as Violent Python uses.  That is the recommended approach.
- Another is to use regular expressions, which are *not* recommended for parsing XML.
- A third, which will only work if your input is already in the form that you have given, is just to compute the positions of the URL's and index into the strings using those.